# not getting point predictions from sagemaker clarify

Tags: aws, shap, sagemaker

I wanted to create shap values for my predictions in sagemaker. I found out that I can use "clarify" functionality in sagemaker to get shap values. However, I want to get point predictions as well. The bias config in clarify can include a prediction function but it seems its just for the train data. I wonder how I can include the predict function in the shap.config part of that so it gives me both individual predictions as well as SHAP values.